# How to fix 2 wires into this plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cord-and-plug

I purchased an axial fan for a refrigerator but it just has 2 wires sticking out. It came with a wall socket plug and cable but on the end of that cable is just 2 small holes.

How do I fix the wires into these holes?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Picture of the ratings sticker on the fan pls.  This seems to be a rather large production error if that, so you want to make sure there is no missing required converter etc.  That said, you may just need to splice.

Comment: Make/model of the fan and/or fridge would be helpful, too. Maybe even links to the mfgr documentation to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Fan is a Sunon DP220A. Added a photo.

Comment: You don't. You should ask how to make the connection properly, not how to perform that particular solution.

Comment: That's not a helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the power is off, then cut the plug off and use wire nuts or your country's preferred type of splice. Junctions inside an appliance do not require additional boxes. Since both wires on the fan are black the motor must be isolated so a good frame connection would be my recommendation for a ground unless the frame is plastic then it won’t matter.

There are small 1/8” spade or male disconnects that could be crimped onto the fan wires but there is a chance these could fall out and any male plug will require a splice so I would remove the plug and splice for a good connection.